# Kivy Slider Trigger Togglebutton

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a slider beneath a ToggleButton and I'm trying to be able to re-toggle the button anytime the slider is moved.

The button has a gif image on it, and the button controls the gif speed by checking the current slider position once the button.state=="down" (is changed to down). It does this by setting the ToggleButton's `gif.anim_delay` property to the sliders position. However, when I move the slider I need to retoggle the button in order to update the delay. Can I toggle it automatically `on_move` when the slider is moved?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to directly set the animation delay from the slider in the .kv file